# Extract only Coefficients from a polynomial Equation in C# using Regular Expression?

Tags: c#, regex

```
String p = "f(x) = 0.0000001122*x^5 - 0.0000184003*x^4 + 0.0009611014*x^3 - 0.0179035548*x^2 - 0.7956585082*x + 79.9900932407";

String expr1 = p.ToString().Replace(" ", "");
var results = Regex.Matches(expr1, @"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(results[9]);
```

I am able to extract coefficients of the equation, but the output also contains the powers of x, which I don't want.
Can Anyone please assist me with this.
I am not much familiar with Regular Expression.

Thank you.

Comment: What are the boundaries of the coeficients? Are they always with decimal point?

Comment: Do you mean [\d+\.?\d+](https://regex101.com/r/O3r7P0/4) ?

Comment: Yes, they are always in the decimal

Comment: @YashMahendra check my answer

Comment: Try this one [`[-+]?\h*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\*|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/qcLN1F/2/)

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas , this one gives an error in C# - "'parsing "[-+]?\h*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\*|$)" - Unrecognized escape sequence \h.'" .                                          But this works "[-+]?\d*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\*|$)". Thanks for your help

Comment: Seems that C# regexes are not PCRE compatible like in PHP. In such case replace `\h` (horizontal whitespace) with `\s` (general whitspace)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `var results = Regex.Matches(expr1, @"\d+\.?\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();` as long as coefficients are numbers represented only with digits.

- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- `\.?` matches 0 or 1 "."

Comment: Why the `/` in the start and end?

Comment: Its how regex patterns are built with strings, but I guess we can omit them here

Comment: It's giving null output.

Comment: Beware, this regex will match 2+ digit exponents as well.

Comment: @YashMahendra as Brian said, if you need only 1 digit exponents you need to alter the first `\d+` to `\d{1}`

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: This looks like it will only work with the current string, e.g 234.5345 * 342  will fail

Answer (score 0):

By regex it may be difficult; with Linq it would be easier: take every two coefficient, you get what you want:

```
Regex.Matches(expr1, @"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Where ((x,i) => i%2==0).ToList();
```

It uses the [indexed version of Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        String p = "f(x) = 0.0000001122*x^5 - 0.0000184003*x^4 + 0.0009611014*x^3 - 0.0179035548*x^2 - 0.7956585082*x + 79.9900932407";
        String expr1 = p.ToString().Replace(" ", "");
        var results = Regex.Matches(expr1, @"(?<coe>[-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["coe"].Value).ToList();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{result}");
        }
        Console.Read();
```

The result :

```
0.0000001122
-0.0000184003
+0.0009611014
-0.0179035548
-0.7956585082
+79.9900932407
```